# Display confirm dialog box on button click using rails 4?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a rails 4.x project and I would like display a confirm dialog box when a user clicks a button in the project.  I created a sign up form, and have a sign up button but when I have the following code,

`<%= f.submit "Sign Upp", class: 'btn btn-xlarge btn-custom', confirm: "test", method: :create  %>`

the confirm dialog box never appears.  I am certain that I have a method named `create` in the controller, but I can't seem to figure this out.  If it makes a difference, (not sure if it does, I'm using the twitter bootstrap gem in the project.)

Comment: Why do you have a `method: :create` for your `submit button`? and try this `<%= f.submit "Sign Upp", data: { confirm: "test"}, class: "btn btn-xlarge btn-custom"  %>`

Comment: that seemed to do the trick, putting the confirm: in the data: {} hash, if you want answer the question I'll make sure to give you the credit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't understand why you have `method: :create` in your `submit button`,but giving it like this would work

```
<%= f.submit "Sign Upp", data: { confirm: "test"}, class: "btn btn-xlarge btn-custom"  %>
```

More Info **[here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/submit_tag)**

Comment: Might be worth noting that this requires jQuery UJS, in case you've removed those from the asset pipeline. `gem "jquery-rails" in the `Gemfile` and `//= require jquery_ujs` in `application.js`